# NSPredicate - Finding object inside NSDictionary inside NSArray

Tags: regex, arrays, parsing, dictionary, predicate

How can I create an NSPredicate that tries to find an object inside a dictionary inside an array?

For example:

```
MyArray {
[0]: Dictionary {
               email: test@test.com
               name: John Smith
               }
[1]: Dictionary {
               email: other@test.com
               name: Mary Davis
               }

}
```

How can I check to see if MyArray contains "Mary Davis" on the "name" field?

I tried

```
NSString *user = @"Mary Davis";
NSString *criteria = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name == '%@'", user];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:criteria];
NSArray *results = [collaborators  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

and

```
NSString *user = @"Mary Davis";
NSString *criteria = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name MATCHES[cd] '%@'", user];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:criteria];
NSArray *results = [collaborators  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

and

```
NSString *user = @"Mary Davis";
NSString *criteria = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"object MATCHES[cd] '%@'", user]; 
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:criteria];
NSArray *results = [collaborators  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

But none seem to work. I know I could do

```
for (int i=0; i (less than) myArray.count; i++){
    NSDictionary *dict = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:user])
        return ;
}
```

And it works, but I need this as predicate because I am trying to fetch data from Parse.com, using PFQuery queryWithClassName predicate.

Is it possible to do this or is it hopeless to believe a predicate will magically transverse the array?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found another solution....

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", user];
```

works, but Parse does not support "contains", as per PFQuery documentation:

```
The following types of predicates are supported:
* Simple comparisons such as =, !=, , =, and BETWEEN with a key and a constant.
* Containment predicates, such as “x IN {1, 2, 3}”.
* Key-existence predicates, such as “x IN SELF”.
* BEGINSWITH expressions.
* Compound predicates with AND, OR, and NOT.
* SubQueries with “key IN %@”, subquery.

The following types of predicates are NOT supported:
* Aggregate operations, such as ANY, SOME, ALL, or NONE.
* Regular expressions, such as LIKE, MATCHES, CONTAINS, or ENDSWITH.
* Predicates comparing one key to another.
* Complex predicates with many ORed clauses.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try using a single `=` ... `name = %@`

Comment: yes it is the same. Trying a different approach, if it works will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently Parse requires a different take into this type of issue, as described here http://blog.parse.com/2013/03/19/implementing-scalable-search-on-a-nosql-backend/

Therefore the correct way in my case would be to create another table Collaborator, with fields "name" and "email", and keep an array of references to this table in the original table.

However since I already had a ton of code implemented, I did a workaround - a created an **additional** array column on the same table, with just the username information that I wanted. In that way I was able to do the query

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name IN {%@}", user];
        query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:table predicate:predicate];
```

Hope this helps someone! :-D

Cheers!